# Manga with a god that sells dreams and a variety of god/animal characters

Tags: story-identification, manga

I read this manga recently but I completely forgot its name.

The main character was a cute medium straight brown haired girl who was very happy busy and optimistic. The male was kind of a god who sold dreams but his business didn’t get a lot of customers

- He had long white hair
- He saved her from dying or something she was in a pool of water and he took her under his wing he said she didn’t have to work. She met more people in this goddess/god-realm-like-bird including a brother and sister whose older sister was killed by humans
- A blind man who cared for a coma patient
- A spider redhead woman who the goose man had a crush on.
- A mermaid queen who cast her son off to help him grow up.
- Her son is sad because of the girl he left behind when he was cast off on earth.

Answer (score 6):

It's called *[Kochou no Yumeji](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/kochou-no-yumeji)* by author Shima. It's a webtoon.

The girl with brown hair is named Kochou. It was given to her after the god/youkai saved her life. She never mentioned her real name just that she wanted to feel needed.

The God/youkai name is Shiro-Gane; he has long silver hair and wears a white kimono with a blue sash on the left shoulder. He inserted a butterfly dream into Kochou so she could live, it's forbidden because humans have family who will missed the person who becomes a youkai. He has two helpers named Mejiro and Uguisu, one is in a red kimono and the other is in a light green kimono. Shiro-gane sells dreams to youkai but he keeps odd hours so that's why he doesn't get many costumes.

They live in a town with youkai and the town but on the sides of a hole where if you fall down the hole you won't come back. The bother and sister youkai are cranes named Miyuki (sister) and Miyuki (brother). Miyuki doesn't really hate humans because she saw her sister's love for her human husband. The brother hates humans because he blames them for killing their sister. They make kimonos, which is how the older sister dies. Her husband tried to sell her a kimono that she made and brought unwanted visitors that ended up killing her when they were threatening the husband.

The mermaid one is true. Kochou altered the dream to help the boy mermaid find peace with his past loved one. His mom, the queen mermaid, was angry with the village that tried to harm her son. She made it rain until the town was wiped out and people died including the prince's love.

I searched under fantasy and webtoon in Mangarock.

Comment: You should really be editing this into the answer you've already got. Also if you've accidentally created two accounts you can merge them [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to find steps on getting them merged.

Comment: Also, you may want to break both this and your previous answer into paragraphs, so they're easier to read. Right now it's just a wall of text.

Comment: If you found the manga, you should post the link

Comment: I'm not certain that there's a legal link to the pages themself, so I linked to the Animelist.com entry